# No se porque solo me da error al final?

Tags: c++, lista

intento imprimir los objetos que me da la funcion buscarCliente y buscarProducto, y no puedo solo me lanza "Run failed" eh intentado utilizar el depurador pero esta dañado, y e intentado varias cosas pero no me han dado resultado, llevo 10 días o mas intentado pero creo que todo el demás código esta bien solo lo que creo que falla son esas dos funciones y no se si también la estoy imprimiendo bien

este es el main.cpp

```
#include "almacen.h"
#include "cliente.h"
#include "funcionario.h"
#include "producto.h"
#include "persona.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long codigo;
    long nuip;
    cout << "Ingrese su numero de identificacion: "<<endl;
    cin >> nuip;
    cout << "Ingrese el codigo del producto: "<<endl;
    cin >> codigo;

    cliente * clienteNuevo =  new cliente(3122137823,new persona(nuip, "zapata"));
    producto * productoNuevo = new producto("Coca cola",codigo,18000);
    list<cliente*> * clientesIngresados = new list<cliente*>();
    clientesIngresados->push_back(new cliente(31241313, new persona(13, "juan")));
    clientesIngresados->push_back(new cliente(31121313,new persona(107764374, "castro")));
    clientesIngresados->push_back(new cliente(31431313,new persona(1076564374, "pipe")));
    clientesIngresados->push_front(new cliente(31543313, new persona(126768778, "karl")));
    clientesIngresados->push_front(new cliente(31761313,new persona(1087264374, "lalo")));
    list<producto*> * productoIngresados = new list<producto*>();
    productoIngresados->push_back(new producto("Coca cola", 17, 18000));
    productoIngresados->push_back(new producto("Pepsi", 1323123, 20000));
    productoIngresados->push_back(new producto("Papel higienico", 3131232, 43000));
    productoIngresados->push_front(new producto("Carne", 1323213, 30000));
    productoIngresados->push_front(new producto("Ducales", 1321323, 12000));
    
    funcionario * funcionarioNuevo = new funcionario("carlos", "juanGallar132","director",new persona(124386778, "pablo"));
    almacen * almacenNuevo = new almacen("castillo",clienteNuevo,funcionarioNuevo,productoNuevo);
    
    //problemas con estos dos bichos
    cout<<"el cliente a sido encontrado y sus datos son:"<<almacenNuevo->buscarCliente(nuip);
    cout<<"el producto a sido encontrado y su informacion es: "<<almacenNuevo->buscarProducto(codigo);
    cout<<"El nombre del funcionario es: "<<funcionarioNuevo->GetPersonaNueva()->GetNombre()<<endl;
       
    return 0;
}
```

este es el almacen.h

```
#ifndef ALMACEN_H
#define ALMACEN_H

#include <list>
#include "cliente.h"
#include "funcionario.h"
#include "producto.h"
#include "persona.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class almacen{
private:
    string nombre;
    cliente * ClinteAlmacen;
    funcionario * funcioanrioAlmacen;
    producto * productoAlmacen;
    list<cliente *> * clientesIngresados ;
    list<producto *> * productoIngresados;

public:
    
    almacen(string nombre, cliente* ClinteAlmacen, funcionario* funcioanrioAlmacen, producto* productoAlmacen):
    nombre(nombre),ClinteAlmacen(ClinteAlmacen),funcioanrioAlmacen(funcioanrioAlmacen),productoAlmacen(productoAlmacen){
        clientesIngresados = new list<cliente*>();
        productoIngresados = new list<producto*>();
    }
    

    cliente * GetClinteAlmacen();

    funcionario * GetFuncioanrioAlmacen();

    string GetNombre();
    producto* GetProductoAlmacen();    
 
    cliente * buscarCliente(long nuip);
    producto * buscarProducto(long codigo);    
 
};

#endif /* ALMACEN_H */
```

este es el almacen.cpp

```
#include "almacen.h"
#include "cliente.h"
#include "producto.h"



string almacen::GetNombre(){
    return nombre;
}

cliente* almacen::GetClinteAlmacen()  {
    return ClinteAlmacen;
}

funcionario * almacen::GetFuncioanrioAlmacen(){
    return funcioanrioAlmacen;
}


producto* almacen::GetProductoAlmacen(){
    return productoAlmacen;
}
// y esta es la funcion que me busca al clinte y me devuelve un objeto de tipo cliente
cliente * almacen::buscarCliente(long nuip) {
    list<cliente*>::iterator it;
    cliente * est;
    for (this->clientesIngresados->begin(); it != this->clientesIngresados->end(); it++) {
        est = *it;
        if (est->GetPersonaNueva()->GetNuip() == nuip){
            return est;
        }
    }
        return NULL;
}
// y esta es la funcion que me busca al producto y me devuelve un objeto de tipo producto

producto * almacen::buscarProducto(long codigo) {
    list<producto*>::iterator it;
    producto * est1;
    for (this->productoIngresados->begin(); it != this->productoIngresados->end(); it++) {
        est1 = *it;
        if (est1->GetCodigo() == codigo){
            return est1;
        }
    }    
        return NULL;
}
```

este es el funcionario.h

```
#ifndef FUNCIONARIO_H
#define FUNCIONARIO_H
#include <iostream>

#include "persona.h"

using namespace std;

class funcionario {
private:
    string usuario;
    string contraseña;
    string cargo;
    persona * personaNueva;
public:
    funcionario();
    funcionario(const funcionario& orig);
    virtual ~funcionario();

    funcionario(string usuario, string contraseña, string cargo,persona * personaNueva);

    string GetCargo() const;
    
    string GetContraseña() const;

    persona* GetPersonaNueva();

    string GetUsuario() const;

};

#endif /* FUNCIONARIO_H */
```

este es el funcionario.cpp

```
#include "funcionario.h"

funcionario::funcionario() {
    
}

funcionario::funcionario(string usuario, string contraseña, string cargo,persona * personaNueva) {
    this->usuario = usuario;
    this->contraseña = contraseña;
    this->cargo = cargo;
    this->personaNueva = personaNueva;
}

funcionario::funcionario(const funcionario& orig) {
}

funcionario::~funcionario() {
}

string funcionario::GetCargo() const {
    return cargo;
}

string funcionario::GetContraseña() const {
    return contraseña;
}

persona* funcionario::GetPersonaNueva() {
    return personaNueva;
}

string funcionario::GetUsuario() const {
    return usuario;
}
```

este es el producto.h

```
#ifndef PRODUCTO_H
#define PRODUCTO_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class producto {
private:
    string nombre;
    long codigo;
    int costo;
public:
    producto();
    producto(const producto& orig);
    virtual ~producto();
    producto(string nombre, long codigo, int costo);

    long GetCodigo();

    int GetCosto();

    string GetNombre();

};

#endif /* PRODUCTO_H */
```

este es el producto.cpp

```
#include "producto.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

producto::producto(string nombre, long codigo,int costo) {
    this->nombre = nombre;
    this->codigo = codigo;
    this->costo = costo;
}

producto::producto(const producto& orig) {
}

producto::~producto() {
}

long producto::GetCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

string producto::GetNombre(){
    return nombre;
}

int producto::GetCosto() {
    return costo;
}
```

este es la persona.h

```
#ifndef PERSONA_H
#define PERSONA_H
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class persona {
private:
    long nuip;
    string nombre;

public:
    persona();
    persona(const persona& orig);
    virtual ~persona();
    persona(long nuip, string nombre);
    
    string GetNombre() const;

    long GetNuip() const;


};

#endif /* PERSONA_H */
```

este es la persona.cpp

```
#include "persona.h"

persona::persona(long nuip, string nombre) {
    this->nuip = nuip;
    this->nombre = nombre;
}

persona::persona(const persona& orig) {
}

persona::~persona() {
}

string persona::GetNombre() const {
    return nombre;
    }

long persona::GetNuip() const {
    return nuip;
}
```

este es el cliente.h

```
#ifndef CLIENTE_H
#define CLIENTE_H

#include <list>
#include "persona.h"

class cliente {
private:
    long telefono;
    persona * personaNueva;

public:
    cliente();

    cliente(long telefono, persona * personaNueva);

    persona* GetPersonaNueva();

    long GetTelefono() ;


};

#endif /* CLIENTE_H */
```

este es el cliente.cpp

```
#include "cliente.h"
#include "persona.h"

cliente::cliente(long telefono, persona * personaNueva) {
    this-> telefono = telefono;
    this->personaNueva = personaNueva;
}

long cliente::GetTelefono(){
    return telefono;
}

persona * cliente::GetPersonaNueva() {
    return personaNueva;
}
```

esto seria todo sinceramente no se donde esta el error y tampoco me funciona el debbuger entonces no se que hacer

Comment: Así por encima, en la función `GetProductoAlmacen()`, cuando usas el iterador, ¿no sería `for( auto it = this->clientesIngresados->begin(); it != clientesIngresados.end(); ++it` )? Igual en el resto de funciones que hacen uso del iterador.

Comment: ok, lo probare pero ojala de resultado, gracias

Comment: solo me devuelve 0 y lo estoy imprimiendo con cout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios fallos en el código. Lo primero es que no puedes usar la "ñ", así que no sé cómo te compila.
Además de esto, tienes dos fallos grandes. La lista de clientes y de productos la creas en `main()`. Pero luego, cuando se crea el objeto almacén, éste crea su propia lista de clientes y productos. Esto quiere decir que no tiene nada que ver con la lista que creas en `main()`. Está vacía.

Para solucionar este primer fallo, puedes crear un constructor que pida una lista de clientes y otra de productos, y que lea la lista creada en `main()`:

```
  almacen(string nombre, cliente* ClinteAlmacen, funcionario* funcioanrioAlmacen, producto* productoAlmacen, std::list<cliente*>*listaclientes, std::list<producto*>*listaproductos):
        nombre(nombre),ClinteAlmacen(ClinteAlmacen),funcioanrioAlmacen(funcioanrioAlmacen),productoAlmacen(productoAlmacen), clientesIngresados(listaclientes), productoIngresados(listaproductos){}
```

Así, cuando estés en `main()`puedes crear el almacen así:

```
almacen * almacenNuevo = new almacen("castillo",clienteNuevo,funcionarioNuevo,productoNuevo,clientesIngresados,productoIngresados);
```

Luego están las funciones `cliente * almacen::buscarCliente(long nuip)` y `producto * almacen::buscarProducto(long codigo)`,que están mal. Te pongo unas que funcionan:

```
// y esta es la funcion que me busca al clinte y me devuelve un objeto de tipo cliente
cliente * almacen::buscarCliente(long nuip)
{
    for (auto it = clientesIngresados->begin(); it!= clientesIngresados->end(); it++)
    {
        if ((*it)->GetPersonaNueva()->GetNuip()==nuip)
        {
            return *it;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
// y esta es la funcion que me busca al producto y me devuelve un objeto de tipo producto

producto * almacen::buscarProducto(long codigo)
{
    for (auto it = this->productoIngresados->begin(); it != this->productoIngresados->end(); it++)
    {
        if ((*it)->GetCodigo() == codigo)
        {
            return *it;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Por último, si quieres acceder al nombre y telénfono del cliente, o al nombre y coste del producto, has de llamar a los métodos de la clase, no a la clase (en `main()`).

```
cout<<"El cliente ha sido encontrado y sus datos son: \nNombre: "<<almacenNuevo->buscarCliente(nuip)->GetPersonaNueva()->GetNombre()<<"\nTelefono: "<<almacenNuevo->buscarCliente(nuip)->GetTelefono()<<endl;
    cout<<"El producto ha sido encontrado y su informacion es \nProducto: "<<almacenNuevo->buscarProducto(codigo)->GetNombre()<<"\nCoste: "<<almacenNuevo->buscarProducto(codigo)->GetCosto()<<endl;
```

De todas formas hay errores conceptuales. Además, habría que corregir cosas como que cuando llamas a un número de identificación o código inexistente el programa se aborta. Hay muchas cosas que pulir.

**Edito:**
Una forma mejor de mostrar el resultado para evitar que el programa acabe abruptamente:

```
 if (almacenNuevo->buscarCliente(nuip)!=nullptr)
    {
        cout<<"El cliente ha sido encontrado y sus datos son: \nNombre: "<<almacenNuevo->buscarCliente(nuip)->GetPersonaNueva()->GetNombre()<<"\nTelefono: "<<almacenNuevo->buscarCliente(nuip)->GetTelefono()<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"No se ha encontrado a un cliente con el numero de identificacion: "<<nuip<<endl;
    }
    if (almacenNuevo->buscarProducto(codigo)!=nullptr)
    {
        cout<<"El producto ha sido encontrado y su informacion es \nProducto: "<<almacenNuevo->buscarProducto(codigo)->GetNombre()<<"\nCoste: "<<almacenNuevo->buscarProducto(codigo)->GetCosto()<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"No se ha encontrado un producto con el codigo: "<<codigo<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: muchas gracias por lo que veo si tengo que pulirlo bastante, me salvaste gracias de nuevo